# apt kills the terminal

Tags: ssh, apt, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have a Raspberry Pi 4 (4GB of RAM) host with Raspbian 11 bullseye.
Today, I was trying to run an ansible playbook to update the system with apt and it faild with a segmentation fault error, which seemed weird. I connected through SSH and tried running `apt update` manually and it killed the connection. SSH output using -vvv was:

```
pi@rpi4:~ $ apt update
debug3: receive packet: type 96
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eof
debug2: channel 0: output open -> drain
debug2: channel 0: obuf empty
debug2: chan_shutdown_write: channel 0: (i0 o1 sock -1 wfd 5 efd 6 [write])
debug2: channel 0: output drain -> closed
debug3: receive packet: type 98
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-signal reply 0
debug3: receive packet: type 98
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eow
debug2: chan_shutdown_read: channel 0: (i0 o3 sock -1 wfd 4 efd 6 [write])
debug2: channel 0: input open -> closed
debug3: receive packet: type 97
debug2: channel 0: rcvd close
debug3: channel 0: will not send data after close
debug2: channel 0: almost dead
debug2: channel 0: gc: notify user
debug2: channel 0: gc: user detached
debug2: channel 0: send close
debug3: send packet: type 97
debug2: channel 0: is dead
debug2: channel 0: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug3: channel 0: status: The following connections are open:
  #0 client-session (t4 r0 i3/0 o3/0 e[write]/0 fd -1/-1/6 sock -1 cc -1 io 0x00/0x00)

debug3: send packet: type 1
Connection to <ip> closed.
Transferred: sent <B>, received <B> bytes, in <s> seconds
Bytes per second: sent <Bps>, received <Bps>
debug1: Exit status -1
```

As it didn't throw any error, I have tried searching `apt update kills ssh` and similar queries, but nothing resolved the issue.

Running `apt-get update` also kills the connection. (I also tried running it inside tmux and it killed tmux)

Neither `sudo dpkg --configure -a` or `sudo dpkg-reconfigure apt` solved the issue, they didn't kill the connection.

EDIT: `apt upgrade` also kills it

What may have gone wrong? Could an unexpected power loss cause this?

EDIT 2: Further investigation: running `ls -l python2` acted the same way. `python2` kills the terminal. I don't tkink it's really related to apt. I'll continue to try things and I'll update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more investigation, it seems that any error raised in bash kills the terminal. I tried running `ls /usr/bin/python2` (which doesn't exist) in zsh and this was the output:

```
ls: cannot access '/usr/bin/python2'zsh: segmentation fault  ls /usr/bin/python2
```

After seeing this result and reading [this question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/107069/how-to-resolve-segmentation-fault-on-raspberry-pi), it seems that the sudden power loss may have corrupted the SD card. I guess it's time to reflash it to a new SD card.